# how to create ios 5 safari like tabs

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, tabs

I want create tab display like safari for iPad. Is there any control which i can use directly to get tabs?  or a way to design this will be helpful.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Take UIButtons, On selection change buttons image accordingly**. I used the same trick in my earlier project.

Comment: Thanx Naveen.just one problem in this, if i select any safari tab, the tab look like part of address bar. how to achieve this.

Comment: For address bar you can have UISearchBar, put it in a UIView. Relatively pass your customized tabbar frame.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a tab view as seen on Safari on iPad. It allows reordering/deletion/addition of tabs (but this behavior can be turned off). The API is similar to UITableView delegate and data source.

https://github.com/mkeiser/TRTabView/